# Getting All Folders in the given http address

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I want to know all directories in the given http address. How can I get all directory names in the web application?
I am using C# in Visual Studio 2010.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: So you want to be able to pass a web address e.g. www.google.com and see all of the physical directories in the file system where the website is hosted?? If so then you can't do that for a myriad of security reasons!

Comment: I believe you will have to be lucky to find one site which gives it as a functionality :)

Comment: It might be helpful to know what you objective is.  Reading this makes it sound like you are trying to hack a website.  I don't think you will find a lot of help here for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, unless that information is exposed by something like a sitemap and you read this in some manner.

It is not possible to 'query' a webserver, GET and POST are standard operations and for those you will need the address (uri) to GET/POST from/to.

Comment: +1 the best you can really do is to get the index page and then write your own spider that will recurse through every link and see if there are any new folders that are mentioned by pages or images in the html, but this won't tell you anything about orphaned folders... overall it's going to not be fun